# Pass SELECT MAX(`Id`) FROM Table to setval()

Tags: sql, entity-framework-core, mariadb, sequence-sql, mariadb-10.3

I want to pass (SELECT MAX(`Id`) FROM `Table` to mariadb's `setval()` function I tried with:

```
SELECT setval(`MySequence`, (SELECT MAX(`Id`) FROM `Table`));
```

but it doesn't work, I also tried:

```
SET @max_value = (SELECT MAX(`Id`) FROM `Table`);
SELECT setval(`MySequence`, @max_value);
```

how am I supposed to do this?

**EDIT** I made a mistake posting the question. I was using SET on the second code and is not working

**EDIT** As I said on the comments I'm trying to do this just once, executing from an Entity Framework Core migration. What I ended doing is executing the `SELECT MAX(Id) FROM Table` and recovering that value from the migration code to  interpolate it later on the `$"SELECT setval('sequence', {value}, true)"`

Comment: Caution! -- If another thread sneaks in, it can get the `Max(Id)` that you think you are getting.  Don't do sequences this way!  See `AUTO_INCREMENT`

Comment: Thanks, it’s a migration. It’s going to be executed once, after a large upgrade on the table is going to be acting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found working workaround using [prepared statement](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/execute-immediate/):

```
SET @max_value = (SELECT MAX(`Id`) FROM `Table`);
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE CONCAT('SELECT SETVAL(`MySequence`, ', @max_value, ')');
```

Comment: I'm no longer working on this project, the question is from 2y ago but, this does work indeed. https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.3&fiddle=f15b42ce025cb78a3411c9a4213a32a8 I'm marking your answer as accepted. Thank you.

Comment: Bonus: EXECUTE IMMEDIATE also works for recreating the SEQUENCE if anyone wants to change the start value. EXECUTE IMMEDIATE CONCAT('CREATE SEQUENCE `my_seq` start with ',  @max_value, ' minvalue 1 maxvalue 9223372036854775806 increment by 1 cache 0 nocycle'); Thanks

Answer (score 2):

In a `select`, use `:=` to assign variables:

```
SELECT @max_value := MAX(`Id`) FROM `Table`;
SELECT setval(`MySequence`, @max_value);
```

You might want to add 1 to the value.

I think you can do:

```
SELECT setval(`MySequence`, MAX(Id))
FROM `Table`;
```

Comment: I’m going to try the second option and let you know. I was using SET but I posted it wrong

Comment: Also, I append true as third argument to setval() so it knows it has to give the next value.

Comment: I tested it, and it doesn't work either :(  You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'MAX(Id))
FROM `table`'

Comment: @PabloRecalde . . . It works in db<>fiddle:  https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.3&fiddle=f87eeba580d767e9e5aba6fdc71e811f.

Comment: I'm afraid it doesn't https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.3&fiddle=68f4b8bf5990e58e75ef24504fa901e0

Comment: I mean I tested it first on my database and got the same error. I'm starting to think that this is not possible with the actual sequence operators implementation, I've tried doing `ALTER` and even `CREATE` a new sequence and it does not seem to like inner queries, nor variables.

Comment: @PabloRecalde . . . That error is an artifact because `@max_value` is not defined in the different code parts of the window.  That is why my db<>fiddle does work and yours does not.

Comment: It is in fact defined: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.3&fiddle=f5bd09f4854bc5f94f43624a7a8b3ce9

Answer (score 1):

In a *stand-alone statement* (not a query), [`SET`](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/set-variable/) is *generally* used to assign value to a user-defined variable. Try the following instead:

```
SET @max_value = (SELECT MAX(`Id`) FROM `Table`);
SELECT setval(`MySequence`, @max_value);
```

Comment: Yeah I was in hurry posting, and misspelled SET. It does not work either.

Comment: @PabloRecalde it seems that setval() function works only with integer literals, and not expressions/variables. Refer: https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/setval/

Comment: I've been there and its not explicit about whether or not you can use them.

Comment: not even the CRATE or ALTER Sequence documentation says that you can or can not use inner queries/variables but it seems that in fact you can't.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that is not possible to do this as of **MariaDB 10.3.16**

I've raised a bug on https://jira.mariadb.org/browse/MDEV-20111 for devs to consider adding this feature or upgrading the documentation to make explicit that it can't be done.

I worked arround this by selecting the value using the Mysqlconnector in c# code

```
private long ReadMaxIdFromTable()
{

    MySqlConnection connection = null;
    try
    {
        var environment = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT");



        var builder = new ConfigurationBuilder();
        var builderenv = builder.AddJsonFile("config/appsettings.json", optional: false, reloadOnChange: false)
                         .AddJsonFile($"config/appsettings.{environment}.json", false, false).AddEnvironmentVariables();

        IConfigurationRoot configuration = builderenv.Build();
        var connectionString = configuration.GetConnectionString("ConnectionStringName");

        connection = new MySqlConnection(connectionString);
        connection.Open();
        var cmd = connection.CreateCommand() as MySqlCommand;
        cmd.CommandText = @"SELECT MAX(`Id`) FROM `Table`";
        var result = (long)cmd.ExecuteScalar();
        return result;
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
        throw;
    }
    finally
    {
        if (connection != null && connection.State != System.Data.ConnectionState.Closed)
        {
            connection.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

Is not as clean as I would like it but, it gets the job done.

Later I use `SETVAL` interpolating the value in the sql string again from c# code.

```
 var currentSeq = ReadMaxIdFromTable();
 migrationBuilder.Sql($"SELECT SETVAL(`MySequence`, {currentSeq}, true);");
```

Also, beware that all the `Up()` code it's executed BEFORE anything gets to the database, this means that `SELECT MAX(Id) FROM Table;` has to result in the value we're looking for before the migration starts manipulating the database.